Determining the supply current of the shift register
I need to choose a voltage regulator, and therefore I need to know the maximum load current in the system. My system has an ATmega32u4-AU microcontroller, a multiplexer for selecting a shift register, and presumably 6 shift registers of the type TPIC6C595.
However, when looking at the register datasheet, I saw several types of input current:

So I have a question: which of the currents should be considered when determining the current consumption? What is the "nominal current" for a given shift register?

It says right there: Logic supply current is typically between 20 and 150 µA, but can grow up to 500 µA. But seeing that you're probably not buying a different voltage regulator for half a milliampere of additional current, it's relatively safe to assume you won't care about the supply current of the shift register itself. If you switch very frequently, expect up to 5 mA logic supply current – still probably irrelevant for your choice of power circuitry.
You do, however, need to take into account the current you're supplying from the outputs of the shift register. And nobody can tell you (aside from yourself) what these would be: if you attach a 100 Ω resistor to each output and drive it high, you'd get a different current than if you only connected high-impedance digital inputs to your outputs.
So, you're wondering about the wrong end of your circuit; what is relevant is probably the loads attached to your shift register, not the shift register itself.

it is assumed that they will activate EMR relay or photorelay. In this case, what will be the consumption of the shift register?

that 100% depends on your choice of load, as said (in your case, relays and similar devices?). Check the supply needs of these from their datasheet.

Do I understand correctly that the maximum current consumption of the shift register will be: (I_load for 1 pin)*8 + (Logic supply current)?

yes, but note that all pins can have very different current draw, depending on what you attach there.So, your "*8" is a bit questionable – it is only true if all pins are simultaneously on and you attach the exact same load to all.

I just didn't specify that I will have the same load... Thank you for answering my questions!

You are most interested in the logic supply current. This is the extra load that each IC will draw from your 5 V rail. The quiescent current, that is the current they draw all the time, will be typically 20 or 150 uA depending on the state of the outputs. However you should design to the maximums of 200 to 500 uA to be safe. When clocking at 5 MHz, the logic may draw up to 5 mA, but typically 1.2 mA. If you rarely clock them, you can ignore this current for battery life, but the power supply must be still able to deliver it in the short term.
The 'nominal current' of 90 mA is the safe sort of typical current that they expect you to sink at the power outputs, and for which they have given a voltage rise specification of 0.5 V. Contrast this with the 'absolute max' specification of 250 mA for the outputs, which is a level which it should survive, but should not be routinely designed for.
